# How to get any particular field from models.py file in views.py file?

Tags: python, django

Here's some of the required section of the models.py file:-

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    read_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Here's some of the required section of the views.py file:-

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

I want to access all the contents from the `content` field, then calculate the read time for all the posts and then save that calculated read time to another field `read_time`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

the Post is accessible as `self.object` in python and `object` in the template